# How to change row bg-color in Vaadin when condition is met?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin23

I am using Vaadin v23 and I am trying to change bg-color of a row when certain condition is met, like below:

```
grid.setClassNameGenerator(row -> row.getRemoved() ? LumoUtility.Background.CONTRAST : "");
```

Why doesn't it work?

I tried to do it with custom .css file and it works, but I would prefer to use built-in CONTRAST style.

```
grid.setClassNameGenerator(row -> row.getRemoved() ? "grid-row-removed" : "";
```

Comment: How is grid-row-removed defined?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli in imported .css file like this
.grid-row-removed {
    .background-color: blue;
}

Comment: Do you have --lumo-contrast configured?

Comment: Where should I configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the CSS must be in the scope of the grid.

So you must define the class in `/frontend/themes/<your theme>/components/vaadin-grid.css`

Then you could do it like this:

```
.grid-row-removed {
    background-color: var(--lumo-contrast);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that, in general, `LumoUtility` classes are intended for layouts and native HTML elements, not for Vaadin components or their parts (such as, in this case, Grid cells).

Comment: Guys, how can I import LumoUtility into my .css file? My Intellij editor doesn't see --lumo-contrast.

Comment: You can't lumo-contrast ist not from LumoUtility but a CSS3 variable from Lumo

Comment: @SimonMartinelli how do I make my .css file see --lumo-contrast then?

Comment: You mean the IDE or editor does not see this. And this is also not possible that the IDE sees it

Comment: You'll find all the available variables here https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/lumo/design-tokens